# Ebean bridge between 3 table

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

All.

I have 3 table "Office", "Project" and "Employee"

**Table Office many to many project**:

Office ebean model

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "offices")
public List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
```

Project ebean model

```
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "project_office",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "office_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
```

**Project many to many Employee**:

Project ebean model

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
public List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

Employee ebean model

```
@ManyToMany()
@JoinTable(name = "employee_project",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
```

I want to have in the table employee_project column office_id. I do not understand how to do it. Help me, please